# Celery task not executing

Tags: python, flask, celery

I'm following this tutorial: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask .
I've imported all the packages and running the app I've got no errors. But when I press send, I'm not getting any mail in my mail account. I've added a print statement in the `send_async_email`. It seems the celery task is not executing. My code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super_secret_key'
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'my_mail@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = 'sender@gmail.com'

mail = Mail(app)    

@celery.task
def send_async_email(msg):
    print "msg sent"
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', email=session.get('email', ''))
    email = request.form['email']
    session['email'] = email

    # send the email
    msg = Message('Hello from Flask',
                  sender=app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'],
                  recipients=['ikram.tanjib@gmail.com'])
    msg.body = 'This is a test email sent from a background Celery task.'
    if request.form['submit'] == 'Send':
        # send right away
        send_async_email.apply_async(args=[msg])
        flash('Sending email to {0}'.format(email))
    else:
        # send in one minute
        send_async_email.apply_async(args=[msg], countdown=60)
        flash('An email will be sent to {0} in one minute'.format(email))
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Edit: Solved my own problem**
I didn't start the celery worker `venv/bin/celery worker -A app.celery --loglevel=info`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In project folder activated `virtualenv` and ran the celery worker `venv/bin/celery worker -A app.celery --loglevel=info`. And now it's working.